# Unnecessary text showing up in the output

Tags: html, tags, output

I am having trouble with this website I'm making. Here's the code.

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="scroll-up-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="max-width">
            <div class="logo"><a href="index">SS Acc<span>ounting.</span></a></div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index" class="menu-btn">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index" class="menu-btn">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="index" class="menu-btn">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="index" class="menu-btn">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="index" class="menu-btn">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="index" class="menu-btn">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="bugloader" class="menu-btn">Report a Bug</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="menu-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="max-width">
            <div class="home-content">
                <div class="text-1">Thank you for submitting!</div>
                <div class="text-2">We will get back to you as soon as possible!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
        <!-- footer section start -->
    <footer>
        <span>Created By <a href="https://github.com/WickedModel">Zarif Sefat</a> | <span class="far fa-copyright"></span> 2020 All rights reserved.</span>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

and here's the output I'm getting:

[image: that's the error I'm getting on the top white bar. The white bar is not supposed to be there, but there is text inside it that says '">']

that's the error I'm getting on the top white bar. The white bar is not supposed to be there, but there is text inside it that says ">

Comment: You probably have an unclosed tag.

Comment: I know, but what tag is it? that's what I'm confused about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I found the problem. I searched for the "> thing and found it :) thanks for your attempt @Gismo1337

[image: Found the problem]

After I found the bug: "There you are you little..."

Comment: That's the reason to show the whole code :-)

Comment: sorry, didn't realize that there was the error in another place :)

Answer (score 1):

Yor are closing the first span after creating the 2nd.

```
  <span>Created By <a href="https://github.com/WickedModel">Zarif Sefat</a> | 
              <span class="far fa-copyright"></span> 2020 All rights reserved.</span>
```

**Solution:**

Use this

```
  <span>Created By <a href="https://github.com/WickedModel">Zarif Sefat</a> | 
              </span><span class="far fa-copyright"> 2020 All rights reserved.</span>
```

Comment: i add my solution into my first text.

Comment: Nvm, I figured out the bug :) thanks for your efforts!